# A problem about partial sum of random number composition

Tags: pr.probability, co.combinatorics

Consider the strong random number composition,

$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n = m$, with $x_i > 0$ and all possible compositions have the same probability.

Let random variable $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^i x_j$

Let $M^+ = \max_{i = 1}^n (S_i - \frac{m \cdot i}{n} )$, and $M^- = \min_{j = 1}^n (S_j - \frac{m \cdot j}{n} )$

I just want to prove that $\mathbb{E}(M^+) = -\mathbb{E}(M^-)$.

Comment: I'll give you a hint.  Pair each partition $ X = (x_1, \dots, x_n) $ with its reverse $ Y = (x_n, \dots, x_1) $.  Prove $ M^+(X) = -M^-(Y) $.  

Comment: @Zsban-ambrus Very impressive, thank you very much!!